# Container not coming in Up state if node modules are not added

Tags: docker, devops

My Container is not coming in up state although the image is being created out of it. But when I insert the below line in last stage the container does come up. COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules /app/node_modules

But I don't want this line because it increases the size of my image dramatically. PFA for the Dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 AS dependencies

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install --production

FROM dependencies AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN npm install && npm run build && rm -rf node_modules

FROM node:14-slim AS production

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/package*.json /app/build/ .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Tried various permutations combinations but didn't work out.

Comment: The Dockerfile you provided creates three different containers. There is no solution to this, the dependencies should be in the same container.

Comment: @Furkan Can you please elaborate the solution.

Comment: You need to copy the module files as you specified because the dependencies in the package.json are used by Node.js. Maybe you can remove unused dependencies in the package.json file.

Comment: It makes sense to me that, if you don't copy your application's library dependencies into the final image, the image will be smaller but won't run; that `COPY --from=dependencies` line is probably required.  What sort of solution are you hoping to find?  Have you looked into why the image size is larger than you might expect?